# Prepopulating fields - Freshdesk on WordPress platform

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, freshdesk

I've embedded a freshdesk widget on my WordPress website.

I need to pre-populate the email field with the user credentials from WordPress when the user is logged in to WordPress website. So far I had no luck on my own or with the support. Does somebody know how WordPress stores user email and how to get it from WordPress?

This is my current code:

```
    <script src="http://assets.freshdesk.com/widget/freshwidget.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    FreshWidget.init("", {"queryString": "&helpdesk_ticket[requester]={{user.email}}&helpdesk_ticket[subject]={{user.subject}}&helpdesk_ticket[custom_field][phone_number]={{user.phone}}&helpdesk_ticket[custom_field][product_id]={{helpdesk.product}}",
"widgetType": "popup", "buttonType": "text", "buttonText": "Support", 
"buttonColor": "white", "buttonBg": "#338700", "alignment": "4",
 "offset": "235px", "formHeight": "500px",
 "url": "http://xxxxxx.freshdesk.com"} ); 
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lets first get the email address of the current user, if logged in.

```
<?php
$user_id = get_current_user_id();
$email = '';
if ($user_id > 0) {
  $user_info = get_userdata($user_id);
  $email = $user_info->user_email;
}
?>
```

And then after this you can embed the Freshdesk feedback widget code to include the above email.

```
<script src="http://assets.freshdesk.com/widget/freshwidget.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
FreshWidget.init("", {
    "queryString": "&helpdesk_ticket[requester]=<?= urlencode($email) ?>",
    "widgetType": "popup", "buttonType": "text",
    "buttonText": "Support",
    "buttonColor": "white", "buttonBg": "#338700", 
    "alignment": "4",
    "offset": "235px", "formHeight": "500px",
    "url": "http://xxxxxx.freshdesk.com"} ); 
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

first get users id   This function is built into wordpress for its other uses

```
function get_current_user_id() {
    if ( ! function_exists( 'wp_get_current_user' ) )
       return 0;
    $user = wp_get_current_user();
    return ( isset( $user->ID ) ? (int) $user->ID : 0 );
}
```

Then in your own template page call the function

```
<?php $user_info = get_userdata(get_current_user_id());
      $email = $user_info->user_email;
 ?>
```

you can use a combination of php jquery

```
 $input = $("your input selector");
 $input.attr("value","<?php echo $email; ?>");
```

from [Ref first](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_current_user_id/), [Ref Second](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_userdata)

Finally find the field you want to pre-populate and fill the value attribute with $email.  I would suggest jQuery, rather than modifying the plugin, since an update will likely wipe any changes you make.

Comment: I'm not that savvy with jQuery. If I  understood well I first need to create this in my functions.php file and afterwards to prepopulate email field with jQuery? Would you be so kind to show we the exact way how to do this?

Comment: you dont need to alter your functions, what you might do is create a template page for your forms then use wordpresses built in get_current_user_id() somewhere in your template before your jquery.  Then put the jquery  in a document ready function on the template page.

Comment: Ahh, I see. I believe that I understand what you mean but not sure if I can do that easily... Are you available maybe to help me out - one on one chat over email or skype maybe? you can reach me on my email primam@mail.com  I would REALY appreciate it if it doesn't take much of your time. 

I want to learn this the proper way...